# File save dialog is empty if selecting mounted SDCard

Tags: finder, macos, file, sd-card

I'm trying to save a file download on my Macbook Pro. When i select a mounted SDCard a target, the file save dialog displays no file structure at all, although i can see it in finder. I currently updated to macOS Sierra. 
I can not remember having had this problem before.

[image]